# QGIS won't add layers into a saved project (but will into an unsaved project)

Tags: qgis, mac, vrt

I have some VRT layers. If I add them into a blank unsaved project they work fine. If I save a blank project and try to add any of the files I get an error.

```
Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /GIS DATA/OML VRT/Buidlings.vrt: `/GIS DATA/OML VRT/Buidlings.vrt' not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /GIS DATA/OML VRT/Buidlings.vrt
```

I suspect this is something to do with paths but I can't figure out what it might be.

Sample of a bit of one of the VRTs

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTUnionLayer name="Buildings">
<OGRVRTLayer name="SD_Building">
<SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1" shared="1">Building</SrcDataSource>
<SrcLayer>SD_Building</SrcLayer>
<GeometryType>wkbPolygon</GeometryType>
<LayerSRS>PROJCS[&quot;British_National_Grid&quot;,GEOGCS[&quot;GCS_OSGB_1936&quot;,DATUM[&quot;OSGB_1936&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;Airy_1830&quot;,6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0.0],UNIT[&quot;Degree&quot;,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[&quot;Transverse_Mercator&quot;],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Easting&quot;,400000.0],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Northing&quot;,-100000.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Central_Meridian&quot;,-2.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Scale_Factor&quot;,0.9996012717],PARAMETER[&quot;Latitude_Of_Origin&quot;,49.0],UNIT[&quot;Meter&quot;,1.0],AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;27700&quot;]]</LayerSRS>
<Field name="ID" type="String" src="ID" width="38"/>
<Field name="FEATCODE" type="Real" src="FEATCODE" width="38"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
<OGRVRTLayer name="SE_Building">
<SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1" shared="1">Building</SrcDataSource>
<SrcLayer>SE_Building</SrcLayer>
<GeometryType>wkbPolygon</GeometryType>
<LayerSRS>PROJCS[&quot;British_National_Grid&quot;,GEOGCS[&quot;GCS_OSGB_1936&quot;,DATUM[&quot;OSGB_1936&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;Airy_1830&quot;,6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0.0],UNIT[&quot;Degree&quot;,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[&quot;Transverse_Mercator&quot;],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Easting&quot;,400000.0],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Northing&quot;,-100000.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Central_Meridian&quot;,-2.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Scale_Factor&quot;,0.9996012717],PARAMETER[&quot;Latitude_Of_Origin&quot;,49.0],UNIT[&quot;Meter&quot;,1.0],AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;27700&quot;]]</LayerSRS>
<Field name="ID" type="String" src="ID" width="38"/>
<Field name="FEATCODE" type="Real" src="FEATCODE" width="38"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
```

I really like the way the VRTs work when they work and I know they are not fully supported but this behaviour seems odd.

QGIS 2.18 Mac OSX 10.11.6 KyngChaos

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the VRTs but in the .QLR I used to group and style the VRTs.

the paths in the .QLR read as:

```
./OML VRT/RailStation.vrt
```

when they should read:

```
/GIS DATA/OML VRT/RailStation.vrt
```

I don't know why QGIS has saved them like this but adding in the full path seems to have fixed things for now